# Como pegar um valor de um método Static

Tags: java

boa noite.

Estou implementando um código onde guarda a quantidade de comparações e o tempo de ordenação da pesquisa binária.
Então, estou guardando os dados em um arquivo texto para fazer uma analise depois.

Só que estou com um problema na hora de armazenar a quantidade de vezes que faz a comparação. A lógica para guardar o arquivo texto está dentro do Main.. E tenho um método statico `pesquisa_bin` para contabilizar `variavel que contabiliza -> vtc`, preciso colocar essa variável dentro do meu arquivo texto, mas não estou sabendo como retorno esse dado do método.

Segue o código...

```
    package br.pesquisaBinaria;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PesquisaBinaria {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;

        for (int cnt_tamanho = 1; cnt_tamanho <= 2; cnt_tamanho++) {
            if (cnt_tamanho == 1)
                n = 100;
            else
                n = 1000;

            int vpesq, vret, k;
            int item[] = new int[n];


        Random gerador = new Random();
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Aguarde... Gerando vetor");
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){
            item[k]=gerador.nextInt(100*2);
        }
        imprime(item);

        double tempoi = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\n*********ORDENADO....");
        int i, menor, j, aux;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            menor = i;
            for(j=menor+1;j<n;j++){
                if(item[j] < item[menor]){
                    menor = j;
                }
            }
            if(menor != i){
                aux = item[i];
                item[i] = item[menor];
                item[menor] = aux;
            }
        }
        imprime(item);
        System.out.println("*********PESQUISA BINÁRIA....");
        System.out.println("*********Entre com o número para ser pesquisado");
        vpesq=ler.nextInt();


        vret = pesquisa_bin(item, vpesq);


        if(vret == -1){
            System.out.println("Não encontrado.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Encontrado na posição: " + vret);
        }


        double tempof = System.nanoTime();
        double tempom = tempof - tempoi;
        tempom = tempom/1000000000.0;
        System.out.printf("Tempo gasto: %.10f \n", tempom);

        try {
            // aberto para operações de saída através do objeto arq instanciado e criado a
            // partir da classe FileWrite

            FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("PesquisaBinaria.txt", true);
            // o objeto de gravação gravaArq é associado a um fluxo de saída de dados
            // baseado
            // em caracteres através da classe PrinterWriter.

            PrintWriter gravaArq = new PrintWriter(arq, true);
            // gravaArq.write(qtvezes, ctcomp, cttroca, tempom);
            gravaArq.printf("%2d ; %2d ; %.10f ; %n", vtc, tempom, chave);
            gravaArq.close();
            arq.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERRO - NÃO DEU CERTO");
        }

    }
   }
    public static int pesquisa_bin(int array[], int chave){
        int esq = 0;
        int dir = array.length-1;
        int vtc = 0;
        int meio;
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Procurando o número: " + chave);

        do{
            meio =esq + (dir - esq)/2;
            vtc++;
            if(chave < array[meio]) {
                dir=meio-1;
            }
            vtc++;    
           if(chave > array[meio])
               esq=meio+1;
            else 
                return meio;
         }while(esq<=dir);
        System.out.println("Não encontramos este número e executamos" + vtc + " interações para isso");
        // PRECISO RETORNAR ESSE VTC E COLOCAR DENTRO DO gravaArq.write(..)
         return -1;

    }

    public static void imprime(int array[]){
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi exatamente o que você queria, mas não seria só retornar o vtc no método pesquisa_bin? Alterei também o que está sendo salvo no txt, esta marcado no código onde alterei.

```
Encontrado na posição: 49 | Tempo gasto:1.3941877 | Número procurado: 11
Encontrado na posição: 499 | Tempo gasto:8.3070148 | Número procurado: 55
Encontrado na posição: 49 | Tempo gasto:1.9158849 | Número procurado: 12
```

---

```
public class PesquisaBinaria {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;

        for (int cnt_tamanho = 1; cnt_tamanho <= 2; cnt_tamanho++) {
            if (cnt_tamanho == 1)
                n = 100;
            else
                n = 1000;

            int vpesq, vret, k;
            int item[] = new int[n];

            Random gerador = new Random();
            Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print("Aguarde... Gerando vetor");
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                item[k] = gerador.nextInt(100 * 2);
            }
            imprime(item);

            double tempoi = System.nanoTime();

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("\n********* ORDENADO....");
            int i, menor, j, aux;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                menor = i;
                for (j = menor + 1; j < n; j++) {
                    if (item[j] < item[menor]) {
                        menor = j;
                    }
                }
                if (menor != i) {
                    aux = item[i];
                    item[i] = item[menor];
                    item[menor] = aux;
                }
            }
            imprime(item);
            System.out.println("********* PESQUISA BINÁRIA....");
            System.out.println("********* Entre com o número para ser pesquisado");
            vpesq = ler.nextInt();

            vret = pesquisa_bin(item, vpesq);

            if (vret == -1) {
                System.out.println("Não encontrado.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Encontrado na posição: " + vret);
            }

            double tempof = System.nanoTime();
            double tempom = tempof - tempoi;
            tempom = tempom / 1000000000.0;
            System.out.printf("Tempo gasto: %.10f \n", tempom);

            try {
                // aberto para operações de saída através do objeto arq instanciado e criado a
                // partir da classe FileWrite

                FileWriter arq = new FileWriter("PesquisaBinaria.txt", true);
                // o objeto de gravação gravaArq é associado a um fluxo de saída de dados
                // baseado
                // em caracteres através da classe PrinterWriter.

                PrintWriter gravaArq = new PrintWriter(arq, true);
//               gravaArq.write(qtvezes, ctcomp, cttroca, tempom);

                //***********************
                //MUDEI aqui
                //***********************
                gravaArq.print("Encontrado na posição: " + vret + " | Tempo gasto:" + tempom + " | Número procurado: "+ vpesq + "\r\n");
                gravaArq.close();
                arq.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERRO - NÃO DEU CERTO");
            }

        }
    }

    public static int pesquisa_bin(int array[], int chave) {
        int esq = 0;
        int dir = array.length - 1;
        int vtc = 0;
        int meio;
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Procurando o número: " + chave);

        do {
            meio = esq + (dir - esq) / 2;
            vtc++;
            if (chave < array[meio]) {
                dir = meio - 1;
            }
            vtc++;
            if (chave > array[meio])
                esq = meio + 1;
            else
                return meio;
        } while (esq <= dir);
        System.out.println("Não encontramos este número e executamos" + vtc + " interações para isso");
        // PRECISO RETORNAR ESSE VTC E COLOCAR DENTRO DO gravaArq.write(..)
        //***********************
        //MUDEI aqui
        //***********************
        return vtc;

    }

    public static void imprime(int array[]) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Na verdade, esse valor de 49 está errado, ele não poderia retornar 49, não sei de onde ele está tirando este numero!. Eu debuguei diminuindo o vetor, e eu teria que ter um retorno de 3 e está retornando esse 49.

Comment: Descobri, @rnd_rss, me ajudou bastante!! Dentro do `pesquisa_bin` tinha um retorno diferente de vtc....Obrigado!